# Delete all the files in Parent except one

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, delete

If I am inside the path `/parent/child1/child2` and I want to delete all the contents of `parent` whilst being in `child2` except `child1` from the `parent`. So can anyone tell me how will that command go?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using the `bash` shell:

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob
rm -rf ../../!(child1)
```

The `shopt` command here is enabling two shell options in the `bash` shell.  The first one, `dotglob`, makes sure that hidden names will be matched by filename globbing patterns.  The second one, `extglob`, enables some extended globbing patterns (originally from the `ksh` shell).

The second line uses an extended globbing pattern to match all names in the `parent` directory, except for the `child1` name.  The contents of the `parent` directory is two levels above us, so we use `../../` first, and then add the pattern `!(child1)` which will match all names except the `child1` name.

It passes all matching names to `rm -rf` for (recursive) deletion.

Instead of using a relative path in the `../../!(child1)` pattern, you could also use the absolute path to the `parent` directory. According to your question, the absolute path is `/parent`, so the pattern then becomes `/parent/!(child1)` instead.  Using the absolute path may be safer if you are unsure of where you actually are located relative to the `parent` directory.

---

Another obvious way to solve this is to move the `child1` directory out of the way first, delete and recreate the `parent` directory, and then move the `child1` directory into place again.

Here, I'm using absolute pathnames (using relative pathnames would be confusing as we are moving our current directory relative to `parent`):

```
mv /parent/child1 /tmp
rm -rf /parent
mkdir /parent
mv /tmp/child1 /parent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU find, you can use this command

```
find ../.. -depth -not -path "../../child1/*" -not -samefile ../.. -not -samefile ../../child1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Just make sure you are really inside the `/parent/child1/child2`